# How do you link to a Facebook Page in a comment using its PageId?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, links

How do you link to a Facebook Page in a comment using its PageId? I remember it was something like:

```
@[id:name]
```

Comment: It doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@[id:linkname]` will work if you know the Facebook Page ID.

- `linkname` is anyname you want.
- id is the Facebook Page Id

Comment: It appears that this does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `@Page Name` now. You can encapsulate it in `[ ]` if it's a rather long one, but there will be an auto-complete-type list that appears underneath. You don't need to have "liked" the pages you're trying to reference in a comment or post.

Comment: i find sometimes the autocomplete doesn't work though.

Comment: In what instances? It's pretty insistent for me, usually picking up names of my friends that I'm typing even without the @.

Comment: Just recently I was unable to link to the [Jerry White page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Jerry-White/186472828131336) with tab completion.. You give it a try.

Comment: I was able to do it after Liking the page you linked: http://cl.ly/image/1j0F1A2s2I18

Comment: I've had instances where not even that worked. =( It's just buggy and the `@[]` notation is still very useful. Besides, everyone knows about the default way to link without PageId.

Comment: This works (in 2014)!